# Can a servlet determine if the posted data is multipart/form-data?

Tags: java, servlets, multipartform-data, front-controller

I have a servlet that is used for many different actions, used in the [Front Controller pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/FrontController.html).  Does anyone know if it is possible to tell if the data posted back to it is enctype="multipart/form-data"?  I can't read the request parameters until I decide this, so I can't dispatch the request to the proper controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the `Content-type` header in the user agent's request should include `multipart/form-data` as described in (at least) the HTML4 spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Answer (score 22):

If you are going to try using the request.getContentType() method presented above, be aware that:

1. request.getContentType() may return null.
2. request.getContentType() may not be *equal* to "multipart/form-data", but may just start with it.

With this in mind, the check you should run is :

```
if (request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().toLowerCase().indexOf("multipart/form-data") > -1 ) {
// Multipart logic here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can call a method to get the content type.

http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentType()

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2, the content type will be "multipart/form-data".

Don't forget that:

1. request.getContentType() may return null.
2. request.getContentType() may not be equal to "multipart/form-data", but may just start with it.

So, with all this in mind:

```
if (request.getContentType() != null && 
    request.getContentType().toLowerCase().indexOf("multipart/form-data") > -1 ) 
{
    << code block >>
}
```

Comment: Kyle, you changed your answer to be my answer after I submitted the *correct* answer.  Perhaps at least referencing this fact might be cool...

Answer (score 3):

ServletFileUpload implements isMultipartContent().  Perhaps you can lift this implementation (as opposed to going through the overhead to create a ServletFileUpload) for your needs.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.java.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to read the request parameters in order to determine this, at least on *some* level.  The ServletRequest class has a getContentType method that you'll want to look at.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [awm129's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7011086/1529709) - Apache commons' implementation corresponds to this:

```
if (request != null 
        && request.getContentType() != null 
        && request.getContentType().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).startsWith("multipart/")) {
    ...
}
```

You can write it a lot shorter using Apache commons' `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`:

```
if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(request.getContentType(), "multipart/")) { 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()

java.util.Collection getParts()

Throws:
ServletException - if this request is not of type multipart/form-data